# IOS how to decode PDF CIDFontType2 text

Tags: ios, search, pdf, text

I want to search text in pdf in chinese. I am using CGPDFScanner. I can't get the correct text with CIDFontType2.

my font object has `ToUnicode` entry

fontName is **HFKAAO+LinGothic-Bold**

it has `CIDToGIDMap` entry with name identity (pdf document said it means truetype font program is embedded)

CIDSystemInfo 
Registry is Adobe 
Ordering is Identity

it has FontFile2 entry in FontDescriptor Filter with FlateDecode

I found someone said I just inflate the text I got from Tj but that does not work... I used zlib to inflate the text , and it seems that it is not produce correct data.

Is there any sample code that I can study?

I just found https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten but it can not work with chinese....

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem

I just use CMap to translate the string form Tj

there is a bug in my code that I decode the CMap

after I fix the bug, every thing is ok

thanks~